# How to select an HTML element using jQuery or JavaScript and the element's name attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How (can one?) can I open a modal using jQuery or JavaScript, using the HTML element's **name attribute** `value`, instead of using the modal `id`? (I have the same modal `id` so I don't have to duplicating my css)

**I was thinking something like this would do the trick:**

```
<div id="product-description-modal" name="uop-modal" role="dialog" class="modal"></div>
<div id="product-description-modal" name="payu-modal" role="dialog" class="modal"></div>
```

**My jQuery method to open the specific modal:**

```
onShowModal() {
    if (this.showPayAsYouUseModal === true) {
      $('div[name]="payu-modal"').modal('show');
    } else {
      $('div[name]="uop-modal"').modal('show');
    }
}
```

But I have had no luck so far. What am I missing?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: This is not about modals, it's about using the proper selector: `$('div[name=uop-modal]')` should do the trick. (Also, don't use the same `id` more than once; as "id" suggests it's supposed to be unique. Use a class instead.)

Comment: Thank you very much! @ChrisG ;). It works like a charm!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select required element with `$('div[name=uop-modal]')` jQuery selector.